# Manage Multiple IIS servers without shared configuration

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scripting, iis-8.5

We currently have 2 web servers IIS 8.5 in DEV

We will push the servers to production to replace our current production servers

My question is, is the a way to build scripts on the fly to apply configuration updates to production after being tested in production.

We cannot use shared configurations because not all sites are the same but for the ones that are we would like be able to update them through a scripted method. Unless there is a better way.

I am thinking something like SQL when you get through their wizards and you have the option to build the script.

Is there anything like that with IIS 8.5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Configuration Editor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569081(v=ws.11).aspx) within IIS Manager does exactly this.

> Creates a script of the actions that you have recently performed. Opens the Script Dialog window that displays the script for your action in three programming languages: C#, JavaScript, and AppCmd. The generate script functionality is only enabled after you take an action, such as changing the value of a property. You must generate a script that includes your action before you click Apply.
>   Note that the script will not include immediate actions, such as locking a section, editing a collection, or reverting to parent.

You open Config Editor then modify the elements and attributes which define your custom configuration. Once you modify something you will see the Generate Script action become enabled.

Click this and you will see your changes as C#, JavaScript, AppCmd or PowerShell.

[image]

You can then combine each change into one script that you could automate with Chocolatey, DSC, SaltStack, Puppet, etc.